# PC speaker pinouts

Tags: desktop-computer, speakers

Have an old PC desktop box motherboard speaker with no cable attached, and a loose cable that I suspect was once connected to aforementioned speaker.

However, the cable has black wire on pin 1 (or 4) and red on pin 2 (or 3), which does not seem to match the [wikipedia PC speaker pinout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker) diagram very well.

```
Pin Number  Pin Name    Pin Function
1           -SP         Speaker negative
2           GND or KEY  Ground, or unwired key
3           GND         Ground
4           +SP5V       Speaker positive +5V DC
```

Can anybody explain this? Did this change at some point during the last ten years or so? (**Edit**: probably more like 25 years, since the last time I know that speaker worked)

Should two wires be positive/negative, or positive/ground? Does it matter? The speaker has two connections.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling is that is not the speaker cable, as it doesnt match the standard pinouts.  Every PC speaker I have seen uses the two wire configuration: red for +5v and black for ground.

Check your motherboard for the speaker header pins.  Hopefully, it is labeled.  You can always rearrange the pins in the connector to match what is necessary for your motherboard.  Gently press down on the exposed metal tab in the connector and pull the wires out.  You can then reinsert them in a different position or just plug them directly to the motherboard's jumper pins.

Comment: Yes, will check the MB manual. I'm fairly sure it is that cable, but there may have been some reason I was not using it.